# Is measuring motion relative to the EM fields meaningful?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, reference-frames

According to the Lorentz transformation for the EM fields, we know that if there is an electric field of $E^{\prime}_y$ in $S^{\prime}$, then the observer in $S$ moving at $v$ along the $x$-axis would measure both an electric and magnetic fields of $E_y$ and $B_z$. However, it is not clearly said relative to which *thing* this velocity $v$ is measured. Is this measured relative to $E^{\prime}_y$ or to the *source* (say, the electric charges, magnets, etc.) that produces the said field?

One may say $v$ is measured relative to the coordinates $S^{\prime}$ and $S$. However, I am still confused regarding this claim since even in the first place, when we say *there is an electric field of $E^{\prime}_y$ in $S^{\prime}$*, it is not clear whether or not this field is in motion in $S^{\prime}$.

On the other hand, if measuring motion relative to the EM fields is not meaningful, does this address that EM fields are similar to *photons* to which we cannot attribute a relative velocity since they always move at *c* relative to any inertial observer?

Comment: *it is not clearly said relative to which thing this velocity v is measured* What book are you reading??? Any decent book would explain that  $\vec v$ is the velocity of $S’$ relative to $S$!

Comment: *it is not clear whether or not this field is in motion* It isn’t clear what that even means. A field exists everywhere at all times. The value of a field at a point can change with time, and so waves can move through the field, but the field itself cannot “move” because it already exists everywhere.

Comment: *measuring motion relative to the EM fields* What does that mean? How would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

$v$ as used in the Lorentz transformation would indeed be the relative velocity of the two systems $S'$ and $S$. (Or: the relative velocity of different observers!)

One observer, using a coordinate system $S'$ in which he is stationary, measures a field $E'$, and a different observer, using a system $S$ in which he is stationary, who is moving at a velocity $v$ in $S'$ then measures a different field $E$ which you obtain by Lorentz transforming with $v$ (plus a $B$-field, of course).

Neither observer has a preferred role, there is no preferred inertial frame (famously, there is no ether), so it is not about motion relative to the electric field. And so I don't think it is meaningful to say the electric field is in motion. You can have fields of moving sources, of course, and they are changing in time, but the electric field is just a force (per unit charge) measured at every point of your coordinate system and you cannot speak about its motion as you can for a material body, there are no identifiable points you can follow around. (Obviously, I'm talking about classical fields here, not photons.)